# Turning a single file into MVC without Rails

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller

I need to take the single file code below and separate it into a Model, View, Controller (MVC) ruby program that can run by the `ruby` command in the command line without using Rails (for instructions on how to run this program from `irb`, check out the README.md on my [RubyBank](https://github.com/erikasland/RubyBank) Github Repo).

```
require_relative 'view'

class BankAccount
  attr_accessor :name, :balance
  def initialize(name, balance=0)
    @name = name
    @balance = balance
  end
  def show_balance(pin_access)
    if pin_access == pin || pin_access == bank_manager 
      puts "\nYour current balance is: $#{@balance}"
    else
      puts pin_error_message
    end
  end
  def withdraw(pin_access, amount)
    if pin_access == pin 
      @balance -= amount
      puts "'\nYou just withdrew $#{amount} from your account. \n\nYour remaining balance is: $#{@balance}\n\n"
    else
      puts pin_error_message
    end
    if @balance < 0
      @balance += amount
      return overdraft_protection
    end
  end
  def deposit(pin_access, amount)
    if pin_access == pin
      @balance += amount
      puts "\nYou just deposited $#{amount} into your account. \n\nYour remaining balance is: $#{@balance}"
    else
      puts pin_error_message
    end
  end

  private
  def pin
    @pin = 1234
  end
  def bank_manager
    @bank_manager = 4321
  end
  def pin_error_message
    puts "Invalid PIN number. Try again."
  end
  def overdraft_protection
    puts "\nYou have overdrafted your account. We cannot complete your withdrawl. Please deposit money before trying again. \n\nYour corrected balance is $#{@balance}"
  end
end
```

I am looking for a good place to start or a general approach towards taking on such a task.

Comment: What should the application do? Your class `BankAccount` _is_ the model (minus text output, if it's not just logging). What you need now is some kind of `View` and a `Controller` class which modifies the model as a result to an action in the `View`. You must have some specs which state a) which actions must be possible and b) which kind of view you have to create (web, console, desktop, ..) or you will have a hard time fulfilling your clients/teachers requirements.

Comment: The application should Greet them from the command line, prompt them to signup for an account, and then allow them to deposit, withdraw, or show their current balance.

Comment: In that case the app is console based. The methods where you currently have "puts" could be converted into different views (or different methods of a generic view). Your controller should be accepting inputs from the console, calling the relevant parts of the model as required (e.g. instantiating `BankAccount.new` when someone signs up, calling deposit when asked etc), and deciding which view to display next.

Comment: "This assignment is out of my current skill set; it perplexes me." While it might seem mean, the point of the exercise is for you to figure this out. Learning isn't always easy; Often times we spend days puzzling and seemingly making no progress as we explore different means of getting where we want to be. And that's what programming can be until we've learned the patterns and ins and outs of the language(s) we're working with. We're expected to be resourceful and and to figure it out. We don't die trying but we do give a heroic try.

Comment: SO is not for outsourcing assignments, but direction is definitely available. Below I provide a gem I've used in the past to do just what you're trying. Also consider of requiring Rails gems such as ActiveRecord and others in one file to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach would be to create three classes:

`BankAccount` minus text output is your `Model`.

All the text I/O goes into your `View`. Prompt the user for an action or registration. Get the model (for displaying data) from your controller or use the model directly.

Your `Controller` is responsible for a) reacting to user input, b) modifying the model and c) for holding state not directly related to the BankAccount (this point is discussable) like being logged in or what actions are possible from your current state. Your `Controller` receives all actions with user supplied data from your view.

Clean separation between View and Controller may be a bit hard in a console application. Also, there are about a million possible ways to implement this in a MVC style. Most important point: no UI-Code (puts/gets) in your model.

Comment: This makes sense to me. What doesn't make sense to me is how you are suppose to get your view file and controller files to play off of each other or communicate with each other.

Comment: Well you pass your model and view to your controller. If I enter 'withdraw 2000', the view forwards that to your controller. There you decide that the user input means 'call withdraw(user_pin, 2000)'. You need to update the view then, because the model (available money) changed. Often this is done by notifying the view from the model. In your case you should be good if you rerender after every action.

Comment: So theoretically, if I were to put `yes_or_no = gets.chomp`

in a view file, how would I get it to communicate with an `if/else` in a controller file?

Comment: You would call `controller.register(yes_or_no)` or maybe collect more information first and have `controller.register(user_information) if yes_or_no`. You collect data in your view and forward that to your controller where you can decide what to do. I hope you get the overall concept - there is not _right_ solution.

Comment: Lol. I am super confused and poking around in the dark. You get the answer though. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is gonna take a while to grasp fully. Try to find some MVC code examples online (prefer desktop apps without framework use). Nobody expects that you get it right the first (100) time(s). If you have something working and want it reviewed, you can poke me at twitter (same nick). SO is not the best platform for such broad questions.